# Huge offset in Lambert Conformal Conic data using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, offset

I want to display my lat/lon climate data, which is in Lambert Conformal Conic. But when I load it in ArcMap (also in QGIS) it will always be displayed with a huge offset. The data is located in northern Germany but is always displayed somewhere in the ocean west of Africa.

The projection has the following parameters. (This is the griddescription generated by my climate data operator - should be accurate).

```
xunits    = "m"
yunits    = "m"
false_easting = 4000000.f
false_northing = 2800000.f
inverse_flattening = 298.2572f
latitude_of_projection_origin = 52.f
longitude_of_central_meridian = 10.f
scale_factor_at_projection_origin = 0.01745329f
semi_major_axis = 6378137.f
semi_minor_axis = 6356752.f
standard_parallel = 35.f 65.f
```

I have tried all I can – the data will still show up in the middle of the ocean. I tried transforming and projecting it a million times but that’s of no use. It always comes out the same.

Here is a Link to the actual data set: [Climate Data], https://we.tl/t-M1hidT4Wg4

Does anyone know what’s the mistake I am not seeing here?

Comment: If you have lat, lon (i.e. decimal degrees) data then it's not in a projected Lamberts CRS. As it says in your provided projection parameters, Lamberts horizontal units are metres, not degrees.

Comment: I see. But can lat, lon data not also come in meters if referenced by a scaling factor? I thought the scaling factor is the conversion factor from meters to degrees. The lat, lon values in the data set are all integers. That doesnt look like degrees to me.

Comment: No, lat/lon values are always angular, never meters. The could be degrees-minutes-seconds or ten-thousandths of degrees, but it would still be angular.